# Is there any possibilities to add some image, media or any file to emulator in Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Store files on Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358023/how-to-store-files-on-emulator)

I'm trying to add some files to emulator. Is it possible to do that.

Comment: Check out this post = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506661/how-to-import-files-into-the-sdcard-on-emulator-in-android or this one = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358023/how-to-store-files-on-emulator

Comment: if you want to add some file manually then see this [Question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358023/how-to-store-files-on-emulator). It is must help for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `adb push` as [explained here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#commandsummary):

```
adb push c:\somefile.txt /sdcard
```

Comment: Yes it's working smooth.

Answer (score 3):

why not for example

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File mfile = new File(path, "sample.txt");
mfile.mkdir();
```

this will create a "**sample.txt**" file on your sdcard

Comment: I improved your working code to reduce memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

you can also push file from ddms select the device from the device window in the ddms and click on the File Explorer tab now select the sdcard.

Now on right side of File Explorer window two button are their which are enable to you for file import or export to the device to pc and vice versa

here is the image: [File Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1BnJ.png)

Comment: yes, you're right Pratik i can also push any files to file explorer