# How to add files to the SD Card in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, file, emulation

So I created a new Android Emulator and now want to add files to the SD card. How do I do that?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/7358023/1021695

Answer (score 9):

if you are using eclipse,

1) Open the Emulator
2) In Eclipse, Select Menu => Window => Show View => Other => Android => File Explorer

It will open File Explorer Window at bottom of the screen.

In File Explorer window, on Top-right, there is push file and pull file option. Push file will push file to emulator and pull file will get the file from emulator.

Comment: ok, I did that but then I get this error: Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: shortcut Shift+Q - Q

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse,

1) Open the Emulator 
2) In Eclipse, 
          Select Menu -> Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> File Explorer

It will open File Explorer Window at bottom of the screen.

In File Explorer window, on Top-right, there is push file and pull file option. Push file will push file to emulator and pull file will get the file from emulator.

File Explorer -> mnt -> sdcard

then select push button on header and push your file in android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use the command line

```
adb shell
```

to open a shell on the phone, and then

```
adb push <localfile> <remotefile>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card) will help you, it helped me, [another](http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/) link is also available. So check both. and  tell me it helps you or not.